# ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery -- system01.dbf

Tags: oracle

The only way to recover is from media backup? I know I cannot "rebuild" system datafile, but if I don't have a backup - I know shame on me! - Is there anyway to recover database?

Comment: So you don't have a backup? No RMAN?

Comment: Do you have the archive logs for this database?  If not, you cannot recover it.

Comment: And where I can see are there archive logs or not?

Answer (score 1):

Without a valid database backup: forget it.
If you do have a valid backup you could use that to restore the database.
If your database is also running in archivelog mode and you have all archives created since that backup, you can also roll forward the transactions in them and doing so recover all data.

It all starts with a valid backup, or a standby database. No magic involved, just common sense.

You could take a look on [jdul](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdul/)
 a tool that has 'reads datafiles when db is down or corrupted' in it's description. I never used it. Kurt has made more nice tools.

Comment: The backup was not done unfortunately.((((

Comment: try http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdul/ and let us hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

you may try PRM-DUL (which unload data from oracle dbf datafile directly without oracle instance) . PRM-DUL is an Oracle Data Unloader. Currently the Oracle tool DUL is the only tool that can unload data from an Oracle DB when it's down or corrupted.